# Can I use new spring 3.2 with older spring-security 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, version, compatibility

I want to upgrade [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/) from 3.0 to 3.2, but would like to skip upgrading [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for a while.

Can I use new spring 3.2 with older spring-security 3.0 ?

Spring modules used are spring-core, spring-orm, spring-mvc (for web services only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are successfully running an application based on Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE. We didn't have any particular problem while setting this up.

Unfortunately I don't have any source that show this is officially supported.

If you are using Maven in your project, you should force versions to avoid having the same jars with multiple versions in your classpath:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Etc. (specify a fixed version for each Spring jar) -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactl my pom.xml looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I am running slightly different combination - **Spring 3.1.4** with **Spring Security 3.0.5** and it also works fine:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.flex</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-flex</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```